# _z always returns null in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, expo, aws-amplify

I am using AWS amplify studio as my backend service for my react native project, while im fetching field names from a relational model named Dish from cartDish im getting render error and shows { Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_x,_y,_z,_A})}
please help me fix this bug

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList } from "react-native";
import { Dish } from "../src/models";

const CartDishItem = ({ cartDish }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.row}>
      <View style={styles.quantityContainer}>
        <Text>{cartDish.quantity}</Text>
      </View>
      <Text style={{ fontWeight: "600" }}>{cartDish?.Dish?._z?.names} </Text>
      <Text style={{ marginLeft: "auto" }}>₹ {cartDish?.Dish?._z?.price}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  row: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginVertical: 15,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
  },

  quantityContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "lightgray",
    paddingHorizontal: 5,
    paddingVertical: 2,
    marginRight: 10,
    borderRadius: 3,
  },
});

export default CartDishItem;
```

and this is my CartContext

```
import { createContext, useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import {DataStore} from 'aws-amplify';
import { useAuthContext } from "./AuthContext";
import {Cart, CartDish} from '../models';

const CartContext = createContext({});

const CartContextProvider = ({children}) => {
    const {dbUser} = useAuthContext();
    const {sub} = useAuthContext({});
    const [canteen,setCanteen] = useState(null);
    const [cart,setCart] = useState(null);
    const [cartDishes,setCartDishes] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() =>{
        DataStore.query(Cart, c => c.canteenID("eq",canteen.id).userID("eq",dbUser.id)).then((carts)=> setCart(carts[0]));
    },[dbUser, canteen]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (cart) {
            DataStore.query(CartDish, cd=> cd.cartID("eq",cart.id)).then(setCartDishes);
        }  
    }, [cart])


    const addDishToCart = async(dish,quantity) => {
        let theCart = cart || ( await CreateNewCart()) ;

      const newDish = await DataStore.save(new CartDish({quantity, Dish: dish, cartID: theCart.id}));
   setCartDishes([...cartDishes, newDish]);
    };

    const CreateNewCart = async() => {
    const newCart= await DataStore.save(new Cart({userID: dbUser.id, canteenID: canteen.id}));
    setCart(newCart);
    return newCart;
    };

    return (<CartContext.Provider value ={{addDishToCart, setCanteen,canteen, cart, cartDishes}}>{children}</CartContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default CartContextProvider;
export const useCartContext = () => useContext(CartContext);
```

I tried to fetch data from datastore(aws-amplify), cartDish is getting fetched but not the relational model(Dish) in react native, im a beginner pls help with the syntax

Comment: Welcome Faaiz! In CartDishItem you use `cartDish.quantity` for `quantity`, but you use `cartDish?.Dish?._z?.names` for `names` (and `cartDish?.Dish?._z?.price` for `price`), this could be the problem. Have you tried using `cartDish?.names` and `cartDish?.price` ?

Answer (score 0):

The error implies you are rendering an object instead of JSX. I do not see an obvious error in the code you've included. I suspect the issue is within `{children}`.

Try replacing the children of `CartContextProvider` with something like `<div>hello</div>` and see if that clears up the problem.

If it does, examine the JSX within `CartContextProvider` and identify the code that's returning or producing an object instead of JSX.